# Need help saving map

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need help with my map editor, I'm stuck on saving it. When I save, after I put some grass on map, it gets grass everywhere in map file.
Here's variables:

mapMaximumX: maximum of the map in X (it is set as 500)

mapMaximumY: maximum of the map in Y (it is also set as 500)

mapTiles[index]: this is a list with class, each class has ID (0 = empty, 1 = grass, 2 = water), X and Y

```
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.F1))
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < mapMaximumY; y++) 
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < mapMaximumX; x++)
                {

                    if (MapTiles[i3].X == x && MapTiles[i3].Y == y)
                    {

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        MapTiles.Add(new Class1(0, x * 32, y * 32));
                    }

                    if (i3 < MapTiles.Count)
                    {
                        i3++;
                    }
                }
            }

            TextWriter file = new StreamWriter("map1.MAP");
            for (int y = 0; y < mapMaximumY; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < mapMaximumX; x++)
                {
                    file.Write(MapTiles[i2].ID + ", ");
                }
                file.Write(file.NewLine);
            }
            i2 = 0;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Saved!");
            file.Close();
        }
```

Full code is here, if u need it:

http://pastebin.com/qrWbuPtb

Thanx.

Comment: Ohhh so much wrong with that code... Global variable mess, ahoy! I see references to obscure variables (`i2`, `i3`, `num`) that dont appear to be used anywhere in the code except the Update function handling F1, which you say doesn't work. I also see you are declaring globals like `x` and `y` then doing `for (int y = 0; i < ...` etc., meaning you're declaring the same variable name again in a different scope (overriding the inital declaration), which is very confusing. I'd suggest rethinking some of your naming conventions and cleaning this up a bit first.

Comment: I also would suggest moving this question to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com as that's a more focused forum for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
file.Write(MapTiles[i2].ID + ", ");
```

i2 never changes within your loop, so whatever i2 is will always be what's used to write your output.

You need to be using X and Y from your loops in determining which cell to write out.

Comment: @Marcus - You need to address those problems.